# Lazy loading with query builder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables-1.10

I have a large table (100K +) records and I am using datatables and Yarja.

My query starts with

```
$gp = DB::table('GoogleProspects')
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->select([
                'GoogleProspects.id as id',
                'searchRequest as searchRequest',
                'websiteEmail as websiteEmail',
                'websiteHomePageURL as websiteHomePageURL',
                'websitePhoneNr as websitePhoneNr',
                'active as activeFlag'
            ])
            ->get();
```

But it seems to be loading ALL the records rather than the pagination number.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You're using `get()`; of course it's loading all records.  Have you tried with `paginate($amountPerPage)`?  Also, that's not a raw sql query.  That's a laravel fluent query.

Comment: The <sql> tag is there, but I see no SQL above. Are you expecting an SQL answer?

Comment: Datatables allows a variation drop down in the number of records which I wish to keep. I tried that and gotan error "No available engine for Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator"

Comment: It is return as a json

Comment: @Jim Have you already tried removing the `get()` altogether and just using [`Datatables::of()`](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/engine-query#factory)?